# Perl find and replace grave character

Tags: perl, character, replace

I need to find and replace all grave characters in a string with the perl. I try to do this with the follow code

```
$str=~ s/è/&egrave; /g;
```

But the `è` wasn't found. I need to convert the grave characters because i have to insert in the XML file
Someone can help me with this?

As asked this is the code

```
sub ConvertiCaratteri()
{
    my ($variabile)=shift;
    #&lt; <
    #&gt; >
    #&amp; &
    #&apos; '
    #&quot; "
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/&/&amp; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/</&lt; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/>/&gt; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/'/&apos; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/"/&quot; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/à/&agrave; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/è/&egrave; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/é/&amp;&eacute; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/ì/&amp;&igrave; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/ò/&amp;&ograve; /g;
    $form{$variabile}=~ s/ù/&amp;&ugrave; /g;
}
```

for char like & < ecc it works but with grave letters doesn't work.

Comment: If you have to insert it into an XML file then you should be doing so using an XML library, and the XML library would be responsible for converting the character into the character reference (so you should not be doing this is a regex) … `&egrave;` is not an entity that appears in basic XML though, so there is a good chance that what you want to do won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Repair the code that produces the invalid XML. Pass characters to the XML library and specify a suitable character encoding. The XML default encoding UTF-8 is just fine.

### Solution 1: plain characters

```
use utf8;
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $dom = XML::LibXML->createDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $root = $dom->createElement('root');
$root->appendText('è');
$dom->setDocumentElement($root);
$dom->toFile('foo.xml');
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>è</root>
```

---

---

### Solution 2: [numeric character references](http://enwp.org/Numeric_character_reference)

```
use utf8;
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $dom = XML::LibXML->createDocument('1.0', 'ANSI_X3.4-1968');
my $root = $dom->createElement('root');
$root->appendText('è');
$dom->setDocumentElement($root);
$dom->toFile('foo.xml');
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ANSI_X3.4-1968"?>
<root>&#232;</root>
```

Comment: I see, i try to use UTF-8 and my xml file appear 'è' but when i try to display in my web page appear the ?. I asked a way to convert my grave character because for other special character like "<", ">" ecc. I insert in the xml &lt; &gt;

Comment: Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11717775/edit) and explain the whole problem. Explain it so that we can [reproduce the problem](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html#showmehow) on our own systems. How do you display the XML? [Show the code](http://sscce.org) you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You have possibly an encoding mismatch between your Perl script and the file you are trying to process. If your HTML is UTF-8 encoded, you can try putting:

```
use utf8;
```

at the beginning of your script.

Better yet, use HTML::Entities:

```
use utf8;
use HTML::Entities qw(encode_entities);
encode_entities 'è';    # returns '&egrave;'
```

Comment: The [utf8 pragma](http://p3rl.org/utf8) cannot help with the encoding of external files. Read how to properly [encode/decode in Perl](http://p3rl.org/UNI).